# Twitter OAuth failing to work (PHP)

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I have the TwitterOAuth class and demonstration running on a local development server and I cannot get it to authorize. I have entered the new CONSUMER_KEY and CONSUMER_SECRET in the config.php. I have also synced the server time to NTP. I get the error message: 'Could not connect to Twitter. Refresh the page or try again later.'

```
var_dump($connection->http_code);
```

results:

```
int 0
```

ANY help or advise would be appreciated.

I am running PHP 5.3

When I try to ping the api server I can't.

```
C:\Users\Owner>ping api.twitter.com
Ping request could not find host api.twitter.com. Please check the name and try
again.
```

could this be the problem ?

Comment: Can you post a link to the demo?

Comment: https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some issues with this process as well. I don't exactly recall what resolved this error, but I followed [This Tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-authenticate-users-with-twitter-oauth/) (albeit a bit out of date) and made sure I explicitly set the callback URL in the twitter panel for my app. Also, and I believe this one also caused the `int 0` return for me, make sure that if you are going with a hosting provider they allow `CURL` requests.

Comment: Yep. Make sure you have set a callback in the application description in Twitter. Alternatively, that you submit an valid oauth_callback URL at the request_token step. "localhost" will not work as far as I know. In my experience it needs to be an URL that is reachable publically.

Comment: @JonNylander: "localhost" also works but you have to change your callback url from "localhost/example.com" to "127.0.0.1/example.com".

Answer (score 0):

step 1: https://apps.twitter.com/app or go to your app setting

step 2: Unchecked the (Enable Callback Locking (It is recommended to enable callback locking to ensure apps cannot overwrite the callback url)) This box..

save and exit and check..

ThankYou..!